# How google analytics' asynchronous api is able to track clicking links

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

If I have html like the following on my own site how come it is able to track the event? Is it possible that browser starts loading the http://google.com in the same window before the tracking request is made as it is asynchronous?

```
<a href="http://google.com" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'category', 'event']);">click</a>
```

In case of using the synchronous API the browser obviously waits until the script in the onclick is ran, but I can't wrap my head around this one.

Comment: i wondered about that also. i think maybe there is a handler for onunload event to check the array size along with a function that gets called on regular interval to check if theres any thing in the array.

Comment: When inspecting network activity in Fiddler, the tracking code is properly being sent to Google Analytics in Firefox and IE, but not in Chrome (tested version 17). So it looks like we won't be able to track the click event if a user clicks on an anchor tag that loads another page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load the **google-analytics.com/ga.js**-script it replaces the array variable **_gaq** with an object. That object has a function named `push`, where all the magic is happening.

If you want to see that code you can do `alert(_gaq.push)` after **ga.js** has been loaded.

By the way, if you serve your pages compressed you might want to check out how to include the **ga.js** script in [shortest possible way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961810/async-google-analytics-code-golf/3962323#3962323).

Comment: So the event tracking is synchronous after all when ga.js is loaded? It doesn't let the onclick handler return until it has got response from ga servers or what?