# Load scripts after page has loaded?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to load certain scripts like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="somescript.js"></script>
```

when the rest of the page has loaded?

Imagine I have a few larger script files like this that are not needed when the page is loaded. E.g. I'm using the Google Maps API that is only used when a button is clicked (so not on page load).

Is it possible to load the rest of the page first, before processing all those script tags in my head?

Comment: Not if they are listed in head, but if you use something like yepnope{http://yepnopejs.com/}, then you can load them only when you need them.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In JQuery you could [do this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) on document ready

```
$.getScript("somescript.js", function(){
   alert("Script loaded and executed.");
 });
```

Comment: Would this also work with loading font files, or is it only JavaScript files? The documentation is unclear.

Comment: There was no JQuery in the question

Answer (score 20):

simply you can add into that script file `defer` parameter

```
<script src="pathToJs" defer></script>
```

you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834077/which-browsers-support-script-async-async) question as well

Comment: No, this is wrong. The `async` parameter specifies that the script gets executed when it is ready, regardless of how far the page is loaded. `defer` is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Works perfectly!  Thanks

Comment: defer loads js after domInteractive but before domContentLoaded.

Answer (score 16):

It is possible. I was doing a similar thing in an AJAX intensive site, but I was loading the Google Charts API. Here is the code I used to load the Google Charts API when a button was clicked on the page.

```
function loadGoogleChartsAPI() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    // This script has a callback function that will run when the script has
    // finished loading.
    script.src = "http://www.google.com/jsapi?callback=loadGraphs";
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}

function loadGraphs() {
    // Add callback function here.
}
```

This uses a callback function that will run when the script has loaded.

Comment: You can use onload event for detection when the script has finished loading. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54032144/5175935 for details

Answer (score 9):

No one mentioned these?

```
$(window).load(function(){
    // do something 
});
```

or

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
   // do something
});
```

Answer (score 9):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ss = document.createElement("script");
    ss.src = "somescript.js";
    ss.type = "text/javascript";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(ss);
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO :) It's always better to add an explanation to the code you're posting as an answer, so that it will helps visitors understand why this is a good answer.

Answer (score 5):

Please see my code. The onload event will occur when the script has finished loading. Or the onerror event will occur.

```
function loadJavaScript() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "javaScript.js";
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.onload = function () {
        console.log('script was loaded successfully');
    }
    script.onerror = function (e) {
        console.error('script.onerror');
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

Thanks to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5491183/5175935).

Also see [my code](https://github.com/anhr/commonNodeJS/tree/master/loadScriptNodeJS) of the load of the script.

Answer (score 2):

To just allow the page to show before your script is loaded, use the `async` attribute:

```
<script src="//url/to/script.js" async></script>
```

To hide the loading spinner in the browser, append the script tag after the page finished loading:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = '//url/to/script.js';
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

use the getScript method of jquery! or try simply to put this script on the end of the page?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible by dynamically injecting the JavaScript files from code. There are lots of libraries which you can use:[RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), [HeadJS](http://headjs.com/) etc. Recently I found [this](https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0Aqln2akPWiMIdERkY3J2OXdOUVJDTkNSQ2ZsV3hoWVE#gid=2) document which compares lots of JavaScript loader libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that's completely possible. Add an `onLoad="foo();"` event to your `<body>` tag and have it invoke your scripts.  You'll need to wrap your external JS in a function and do something like:

```
//EXTERNAL JS (jsstuff.js)

function Mojo() {
    document.getElementById('snacks').style.visibility = "visible";
    alert("we are victorious!");
}

//YOUR HTML

<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript'></script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad='Mojo();'>
        <div id='snacks'>
            <img src='bigdarnimage.png'>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```