# include js library to head from inside the body and specific to only one page

Tags: php, structure, javascript, html-head

I use google charts js library in only one page in my project and I have external and global head and footer. head tags are in head.php file and required js libraries are included in there. Anatomy of my pages are like this:

```
<?php
require('header.php');
?>

<div>my body elements of this page lie here </div>

<?php
require('footer.php');
?>
```

I can include google charts library in header.php. It will be loaded in every page, but I need it in only one page. So, I do not want to make the loading progress slow. How can I include that library only if I am loading this particular page? Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have already loaded it in one page then it will be cached for all subsequent pages and shouldn't be a drag on resources. You could always create a special header file for the one page.

Comment: What @JayBlanchard said but you could also write a PHP function that monitors the currently open URL and if this matches your charts page then echo out the JS library you need into your header HTML...

Answer (score 3):

Simply add a variable before you include the header, and check for that variable within header.php

```
<?php
//page that requires the js
$chartjs = true;
require('header.php');
?>

<div>my body elements of this page lie here </div>

<?php
require('footer.php');
?>
```

.

```
<?php
//header.php
if(isset($chartjs) && $chartjs){
    //inlcude js file here
}
```

Comment: The footer may include the HTML closing tag so the PHP might not be so simple... he'd need to write it into the `footer.php` if this is the case. Great and simple answer though :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, You could load it conditionally via JavaScript depending on the context of the page, I'll use jQuery here for ease of use with the Ajax side of it, so for example:

### Page Body:

`<div class="chart"></div>`

### Header.php

```
<script>
     var $charts = $('.chart');
     if ( $charts.length ) {
         $.getScript("charts.js", function(){
              $charts.plot(); //init.
         });
     }
</script>
```

This will delay the loading of the chart however though. Also, for reference how to load without the jQuery library, see [Load scripts after page has loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490996/load-scripts-after-page-has-loaded) for some good references on post-page load scripts.

Reference [**`$.getScript`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

Answer (score 0):

You have several options. One is what Steve recommended in his answer.

I'd like to use this in chart page:

```
require('header.php');
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="chart.js"></script>

<div>my body elements of this page lie here </div>

<?php
require('footer.php');
```

The other is to check the `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`, and include only in header, it this is the specified page.