# load script tags inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have dynamically loaded a page with `div id="example"`. So only the contents of the id will be executed. I also have script tag inside div which is not being executed. I have tried using eval but it failed.

```
<div id="example">
    <script>
        alert("Welcome");
    </script>
</div>
```

In a js file,

```
var ele=document.getElementByTagName('script');
eval(ele.innerHTML);
```

Attached the plunker link below
https://plnkr.co/edit/LrfxZERqI6gYhKbGvNwQ?p=preview

Comment: Why would you do such horrible thing? You can wait for an element to be added but that's no way to do so, html and JS should not be combined

Comment: @Sindhu- are you saying that you are dynamically adding the `<div ...><script>...</script></div>` into the page, and the script is not being executed? Can you share how that is being dynamically loaded?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load scripts after page has loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490996/load-scripts-after-page-has-loaded)

Comment: It's `getElementsByTagName` (notice the s on Elements), not singular. Also it returns an array like structure not a single object so your use of it is wrong anyway. And as Joseph points out, inserting a script via innerHTML will not be executed by the browser for security reasons

Comment: @Joseph I used Jquery   <div id="abc">Example</div>   <script>$('#abc').load("/home/example.html  #example);</script>

Answer (score 1):

You can wait for the existence of an element to run an script, it's a better and way more accepted solution than running JS inside of elements

```
if(document.querySelector('.my_selector')){
   doStuff();
}
```

If you are addding the elements dinamically, you can then execute the desired code

```
document.body.append('<div class="my_selector></div>"');
doStuff();
```

In case it's asynchronous you can use promises to wait for the element to be added

```
let adding_element = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
  if(!document.querySelector('.my_selector')){
   setTimeOut(resolve('.my_selector'),1000);
}
});

adding_element.then(selector => {
  document.body.append(`<div class="${selector}"></div>"`);
  doStuff();
});
```

Since you are waiting for the user to click in for example `<a class="my_selector" href="#something">link</a>`, you can add an event listener, it will only run when the user hits that link

```
let link_element = document.querySelector('.my_selector');

function doSomething(){
  //some code
}

link_element.addEventListener('click', doSomething);
```

There's endless better ways to do so, but please avoid what you are currently doing.

Comment: I have a tab when I click the tab it loads the div in a different page. Since the script is not inside the div it is not getting executed. <a href="/home/example1.html  #example">Example</a> Something like this

Comment: In such case you can wait for the click and then execute the code you want, I will expand my answer to illustrate this behavior

Comment: Instead of the document ready, wrap it in a function and call that function with the addeventlistener as I showed you in the last example, that way it will run the code in the click event

Comment: link_element doesn't show script tag. I have attached the plunker link https://plnkr.co/edit/LrfxZERqI6gYhKbGvNwQ?p=preview

Comment: As I were telling you, loading scripts from another page is dangerous and out of the standard, this is a correct implementation

https://embed.plnkr.co/Ps1IVJBT9vqiTwbhBxzF/

Comment: Got it.. But I have script tag in each html file.. almost 15 html files with script tags.. I can't have those 15 js functions in index file..

Comment: You can add a data-deploy in the anchor tags, which you can pass to a function that will trigger the JS with a switch/case, for multiple items. Additionally you can simply showing/hidding divs with the content instead of loading the content from other pages

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0pmzzp7e/1/ I will have something like this.. different menus and submenus so I wanna put it in different files.. Also I haven't heard of data-deploy.. interesting..