# Is there a way to combine loading jQuery and Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have the following:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=..." type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script> 
  //<![CDATA[
    google.load('jquery', '1.6');
  //]]>
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '...']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function () {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
</script>
```

Seems like two very different ways to load js. Is there some way I can combine these so the load is most efficient?

Answer (score 0):

For this call you need to load google jsapi first.

```
google.load('jquery', '1.6');
```

If you just want the jquery loaded asyncronously parallel to other script file calls, use the following :

```
var jq = document.createElement(“script”);
jq.src = “/path/to/jquery.js”; jq.type=”text/javascript”; jq.async=true;
document.getElementsByTagName(“head”)[0].appendChild(jq);
```

Comment: thanks. One question. I think async=true is new. Does that work for all browswers or just some?

Comment: @Michael Its supported in new browsers .. check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834077/which-browsers-support-script-async-async