# eval-uating server js file dangers

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, eval

For loading external js files from my server in an asynchronous manner, instead of having to wait for them to load by including in the html head or at the end of the body, I use jquery.get() to retrieve those js files as a string, convert into an object with eval() and assign to a global variable as a property, i.e. (pseudocode):

```
var globalNameSpace = {};
var data = jquery.get('url/foo.js');           // foo.js returns a function with code
globalNameSpace[foo] = eval(data);
// from here onwards, access code in foo.js as:
globalNameSpace.foo.property;
globalNameSpace.foo.method();
```

This also means I can display a html page with a loading bar etc.

The question is, with all the hype of eval() being dangerous with uncontrolled inputs, seeing as this is only to load "controlled" (although probably buggy :P) scripts from my own server (ajax same domain policy etc), how is this more dangerous than simply including the js files with  tags, am I missing out on something?

Comment: Why not simply use `.getScript()`? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: This is safe. Your just better of injecting a `<script>` into the DOM then doing it manually

Comment: I'd seen various "js load module" implementations adding a script tag to the DOM tree, just liked the idea of not polluting it. Anyway what I was interested in understanding was if I was missing out on any eval() evils. Thanks for the quick answers!

Answer (score 0):

There's no more danger than including the JavaScript normally using blocking `<script>` tags.

But you should consider either using the [`async`](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-async) attribute, which [is supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834077/which-browsers-support-script-async-async/6766189#6766189) in IE10, Chrome 11, Safari 5 and FF 3.6, or injecting the script element into your document using [jQuery.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) when the DOM ready event is fired.