# Javascript script prevent waiting for script to load (PantherAds)

Tags: javascript, timeout

Well I recently got into PantherAds and got my ad script to place on my website. However I found out that when the script (/iframe) of Pantherads on my website isn't loading, the rest of my website isn't loading either. In other words: it's waiting for Pantherads to fully load before it will continue to load the rest of my website. Now what I'd like to do is either make sure it loads the rest of the page at the same time, so that my website won't be bothered when PantherAds script isn't loading, or I'd like to set a timeout for the Pantherads script. E.g. if it hasn't loaded within 5 seconds, then just skip it.

Does anyone know how to do this? Or can anyone help me out on this? Would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards.

**UPDATE:**
This is the Pantherads script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://pantherads.com/ads/CODEHERE"></script>
```

It's said to use an iframe to show the ad.

Comment: It would help immensely if you'd post the code you use to import the script.

Comment: Ah sorry, updated my post with the script :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include your `<script> </script>` tags of PantherAds just before closing `</body>` tag.

It will load only after your page is loaded.

Comment: But the ad wouldn't appear on the correct place then. How would I fix that?

Comment: You can use defer attribute then,

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 different solutions:

- add the "async" attribute to the script declaration (

  add the "defer" attribute. It's supported by all browsers (even by IE5). I will delay the script execution until the body is not fully parsed/rendered.

  place you script just before the end of the page (, suggested by Jashwant)

P.S. if I were you I would review the entire execution/priority map of all the scripts, by putting some of them (mostly Google analytics and similar) to async mode. JQuery external scripts to defer and so on. You might get a significant speed increase.

Answer (score 1):

Google, and many others use the following JavaScript snippet to perform an async load of a JavaScript file; just add the following code to a `script` block on your page:

```
(function() {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.async = true;
    s.src = 'http://pantherads.com/ads/CODEHERE';
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
})();
```

Comment: @Jashwant See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834077/which-browsers-support-script-async-async/6766189#6766189