# Must the <script> tag, with the jQuery library reference, be inside the <head> or <body> tag?

Tags: jquery, html, head, document-body

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [Where should I put  tags in HTML markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup)

I always thought that it's better to put it in the head (maybe because it is loaded first in the head and also to group all the scripts in the head for easy reading), but I found several examples over Internet ([Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) documentation, [ASP.NET MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC) 4, etc.) where the script tag with the reference to jQuery (*<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>*) is inserted into the body:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

What's the best practice?

Comment: You usually put them just before the closing body-tag, so the page can start loading images and other HTML before doing several .js-files requests.

Comment: There are pros and cons for both approaches. The best for page load would be to put it at the bottom, however that can make it very difficult for certain structures, such as an application built around server-side code returning the same footer and header for every page, where each page has it's own js defined within it.

Comment: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

Answer (score 2):

> the `<script>` tag with the jQuery library reference must be inside `<head>` or `<body>` tag?

Yes, either.

There can be performance benefits to putting it in one or the other (particularly at the end of the body) although that is a tradeoff between delaying when the JS can run and blocking the loading of other content while the JS downloads and parses.

Comment: Surely there's something to be added here regarding `aync` loading? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834077/which-browsers-support-script-async-async

Answer (score 0):

They go at the end of the body.

Comment: That is, before the `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is use `script` at the bottom of the page. It will decrease the page rendering speed.

Read the article *[Yahoo best practices for page speed](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom)*, especially section *"Put Scripts at the Bottom"*.

Comment: Re *"at the bottom of the page"*: But before the `</body>` tag. If the 'script' tag is ***after*** '</body>', [HTML validation](https://pmortensen.eu/temp2/script_tag_after_ending_body_tag_but_before_ending_html_tag.html) will result in *"[Error: Stray start tag script](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fpmortensen.eu%2Ftemp2%2Fscript_tag_after_ending_body_tag_but_before_ending_html_tag.html)"* (check option *"source"* and click *"check"* to see the HTML source). If it is ***before***, [it validates](https://pmortensen.eu/temp2/script_tag_before_ending_body_tag.html).

Answer (score 0):

From *[Put Scripts at the Bottom](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom)*:

> The problem caused by scripts is that they block parallel downloads. . If a script can be deferred, it can also be moved to the bottom of the page. That will make your web pages load faster.

So yeah... At the bottom of your `<body>`.