# Why does Google Analytics dynamically inject javascript into the page

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Why do I need to use:

```
(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

Instead of:

```
<script async="true" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script>
```

The only reason I can see is that they have a different subdomain for SSL. If it weren't for that is there any reason to use this script injection technique?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Being able to serve out `http` or `https` depending on the protocol of the parent page is one reason.
2. As the script is injected via a `script` tag inserted via running JS code, it does not block page loading. This is another reason. But this can very well be achieved via the new HTML5 [async](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-async) attribute too (but this is not compatible with older browsers - and GA absolutely needs to be compatible with pretty much all of them)

Comment: Primarily point #2 (and the subdomain). Point #1 could be solved by [just starting the URL without a protocol](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/skipping-protocol.html) (... `src="//www.google-analytics.com/ga.js"` ...).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Yes, that is also correct, but will it work for all browsers including older ones. Bcoz GA has to be super compatible with all i imagine.

Comment: Also, `location.protocol` can be used to dynamically detect the right protocol.

Comment: @techfoobar: Compatible with anything you want to throw at it, see the link I added. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Thank you for the informative article. So this in combo with async should mean no more script, maybe few more years down the line..

Comment: @techfoobar: Yeah, `async` or `defer` (or both).

Comment: If you are on a HTTPS page, for example an eCommerce checkout, then the page will likely be HTTPS meaning that if you reference http://www.google.com/analytics.js for example then you will get security warnings. Google provide the code you require to handle this eventuality with the `document.location.protocol` ternary operator.

Comment: Thanks for your combined thoughts. I think you are right that it's about compatibility with older browsers. Found this a useful S.O question on which browsers support the async attribute on script tag. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834077/which-browsers-support-script-async-async