# What is the difference between including async javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, asynchronous

For example, google+ gives this code:

```
<!-- Place this tag after the last +1 button tag. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

but why not just this:

```
<script async src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14815520/921204

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`async` and its cousin `defer`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-async) aren't [supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=script-async) by all browsers. (IE didn't get them until IE10, for instance.) The first method will always be async, the second won't be on browsers that don't support `async`.

The reason the first will always be async is that `script` elements added to the DOM dynamically like that don't hold up the parsing and rendering of the document, whereas `<script>` tags inline in the HTML content *do* (barring the use — and support — of `async` or `defer`).

Comment: According to [this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=script-async), Opera is the only modern browser that doesn't support it.

Comment: @Whymarrh: Depends on your definition of "modern." IE8 will be with us a long, long time. (Amusingly, I was just adding a link to caniuse to the answer as you commented!)

Answer (score 0):

There are good explanation: [Which browsers support <script async="async" />?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834077/which-browsers-support-script-async-async)

Yes, now most browsers support async but usually you need 100% guaranty that you code works, and then you need to use first form